# How to prevent execution of controller actions based on condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller with many actions.
I need to prevent execution of **some** actions based on this condition:

```
if (Session["MyObject"] == null) return RedirectToAction("Introduction");
```

It should redirect to a default Introduction action.

I can put this condition in each action, but I would like to define this condition just in one place, like in controller's constructor maybe.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: 2 ideas. Custom Authorization filter or custom Action Filter. You can either populate the filter with logic that decides which action is affected or by which actions you apply the filter

Comment: I am a Java programmer so I could be wrong but wouldn't putting the code snippets you presented in the constructor result in all actions being redirected to the default introduction?

Comment: Sure, I need to distinguish between actions. I guess Dave's advice is correct. let me check..

Comment: Only if the session object is empty. I assume the goal is to populate the session if it expires

Comment: Not really. The session object is not set automatically, there is some specific app logic for that. Doesnt matter ;) Thanks Dave, the ActionFilterAttribute suggestion is perfect !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a quick mock up, but I think the idea holds

```
public class CheckSessionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["MyObject"] == null)
        {
            // redirect must happen OnActionExecuting (not OnActionExecuted)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
              new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {
              {"controller", "Tools"}, {"action", "CreateSession"}

        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }   
}
```